# How to set up invoices with invoice_rows once an order is created?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to figure out how to automatically set up an `invoice` with `invoice_rows`, once a reservation is saved.

**Attempts**

Before even including the order_rows, I tried generating an invoice for order:

I tried including `@order.invoices.create(order_contact_id: @order.order_contact_id)` after saving the order in create, but this resulted in an empty array:

```
Order.last.invoice => []
```

Afterwards I probably should iterate over all products belonging to a order and include them as invoice_rows in invoice. But not sure how.

**Note**

The actual structure is more complex and consequently I need all my tables.

**Code**

models

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :invoices
  has_many :order_products, dependent: :destroy
end

class OrderProduct < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product
  belongs_to :order
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :product
end

class Product < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :orders, through: :order_products
  has_many :product_prices, dependent: :destroy, inverse_of: :product
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :product_prices, allow_destroy: true
end

class ProductPrice < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :product, inverse_of: :product_prices
end
```

orders_controller

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @order = @shop.orders.new(order_params)
    authorize @order
    if @order.save
      authorize @order
      # @order.invoices.create(order_contact_id: @order.order_contact_id)
      redirect_to new_second_part_shop_order_path(@shop, @order)
    end
  end

private

def order_params
  params.require(:order).permit(:order_contact_id,
  order_products_attributes: [:id, :product_id, :product_quantity, :_destroy,
    products_attributes: [:id, :name, :description]])
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you show what you've tried already to achieve this? The code you've shared so far doesn't do anything with `Invoice` or `InvoiceRow`

Comment: My apologies, you're right. I added the attempts incl. outcome.

Comment: Are you doing any validation in your `Invoice` model? You could also output the return value from your call to `@order.invoices.create(...)`.

Comment: @ramblex Use `@order.invoices.create!(order_contact_id: @order.order_contact_id)` to get the validation error you are getting

Comment: Thanks guys! I will add the error message in the question.

Comment: Thanks guys! Turned out the saving of the order didn't work properly and therefore it couldn't create the invoice. So now the only challange is to include the invoice_rows. I will update my question accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested in the comments, I found the error message by using `@order.invoices.create!`.

Afterwards I iterated over each product and created an `invoice_row` for the created invoice.

```
@invoice = @order.invoices.create!(order_contact_id: @order.order_contact_id)
@order.order_products.each do |o_product|
  @invoice.invoice_rows.create!(
     description: o_product.product.name,
     total_price: @reservation.total_product_price(@reservation, o_product)
    )
end
```